# Publish Jekyll Site To Git Repository

Tags: git, jekyll

Every time I run Jekyll it destroys the entire contents of the destination folder.  The problem with this is that my destination directory is a small git repo from which I use to push to my actual server.  Is there a way to stop Jekyll deleting the Git files so that I don't have to generate the contents then copy them over?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could have:

- your git repo elsewhere (i.e. not in the directory affected by a Jekyll deployment)
- have your script pushing that git repo to your server specify a `GIT_WORK_TREE` variable with the destination folder as value

In other words, a `.git` don't have to be necessary in the working tree directory itself.
It can be elsewhere, and your script can refer to the actual working tree through  `GIT_WORK_TREE` or through a `--work-tree=<path>` option.

If your script is part of the destination directory where Jenkyll copies/erases files, you can do the opposite, and mention where the `.git` actually is with `GIT_DIR` variable or with `--git-dir=<path>` option.

To have new `--work-dir` as default options to your repo, you can use `git-config --add core.worktree ../PATH/`, where `PATH` - path to actual working directory relative to `.git`.

Comment: So the Git files don't need to be in the root of the actual directory?

Comment: @kouPhax: exactly. I have edited my answer to add some more details on this.

Comment: Excellent I will have a look at this now.  Thanks.

Comment: @neoascetic thank you for the edit about `core.worktree` config.

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at the Deployment section of the Jekyll wiki? - https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Deployment. It clearly explains Jekyll deployment steps.

And why are you pushing from the destination? That is bad! Push it from some other clone.

Answer (score 1):

I also want this setup.  Found this pull request to fix Jekyll, making it not delete the .git dir:
https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/pull/337

Read my comment there, as:

1. the fix is actually slightly broken (make it .git not .git$)
2. I believe a better solution would be to have this as a configuration variable, to handle other files like .svn.

Anyway, my Jekyll line now reads: `dest_files << file unless file =~ /\/\.{1,2}$/ || file =~/\/\.git/`

Works great! I'm even using octopress (just change your deploy_dir to be public) and comment out the following lines in Rakefile:

```
    #  (Dir["#{deploy_dir}/*"]).each { |f| rm_rf(f) }
    #  Rake::Task[:copydot].invoke(public_dir, deploy_dir)
    #  puts "\n## copying #{public_dir} to #{deploy_dir}"
    #  cp_r "#{public_dir}/.", deploy_dir
```

Now your public dir (instead of _deploy dir) can be your github repo to publish your site (submodule of a branch or my parent repo in my case)

Seems senseless to have public and _deploy with octopress, but I'm happy to hear other reasons why to split public and _deploy dirs - besides Jekyll deleting the .git dir. (I read through the full commit history of octopress, but couldn't find any explanation for why its done this way)

Answer (score 0):

I actually used

```
git clone --separate-git-dir repo git@github....
```

and sovled this problem.

Answer (score 0):

@manojlds, I'm not sure I understand, TPW's default _config.yml (Which I've customized) shows the location of the _site directory as ".", inside of the blog directory which also contains the Git repo. Is there a way to move this directory so that it doesn't spew files all over the place? I think I'm missing something here because either Jekyll refuses to generate anything or the above scenario happens and I have to clean up the mess that's left behind.

Do we have a best practice for where _site can (or should) be located?

Edit: Looking at it, I actually see the following:

source:      .
destination: ./_site

The fact that Terminal can't find the jekyll gem (installed via RVM) is probably the cause of my problem rather than the location of _site.